# Which PCL 6/PCL XL driver?

Tags: drivers, printing, dell

I'm trying to setup a print server via CUPS. I've been told that a generic PCL6/PCL XL driver will work fine, but in CUPS there are a million versions listed:

- Generic PCL 6/PCL XL LF Printer - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.9 (en)
- Generic PCL 6/PCL XL Printer Foomatic/hpijs-pcl5c (en)
- Generic PCL 6/PCL XL Printer Foomatic/lj5gray (en)

etc.

How do I know which one to choose?

Comment: Well, it would certainly help if you told us the exact manufacturer and model of your printer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PCL is the printing command "language" this printer driver uses. It talks to printers that speak "PCL 6" in this case. Just like other printers print PS (postscript) or PDF. Older PCL printers may only support up to v5 for 5C (color). All newer though should support either "PCL 6" or PCL 6XL (for window GUI rendering crap).

You actually don't NEED the name and model of your printer if you knows it speaks PDF or PS or PCL6. That's the great things about open standards.

As for which one.. depending on your desktop interface or CUPS/PDD driver packages, some times you'll see one that says "recommended".. If not, I usually go with the Gutenprint based drivers. They seem to have better standards and quality control. But others welcome to chime in too.

Comment: Typically PPD "drivers" are just metadata files that list supported max DPI values, tray labels and paper sizes to make configuring the printer easier. If you go with the most generic driver, you'll have to set the paper size manually and just know if the printer supports 2-sided printing or if "Tray 1" or "Tray 2" is actually a side-feed or not.